# DBI::dbSendQuery with parameterized query does not work for SQL Server

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, dbi

I have a database table `dbo.address` in my SQL Server. I want to insert a row into this table. I use `dbSendQuery` to send the insert query to the database.

What I want is to use parameterized query, as the example below. I don't want to use `paste` to construct the query string, because it's getting extremely confusing especially if there are many columns.

My code below does not work. The `?` works for mySQL, but not for SQL Server in my case.

Does anyone know how to pass parameters to the query string? Thanks a lot!

BTW, I know my db connection is fine. Pass simple query there works fine.

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                       Server = serverName,
                       Database = dbName,
                       UID = username,
                       PWD = pasword,
                       port=1433)


query = "insert into dbo.address (AddressID, City, PostalCode) values (?,?,?)"

dbSendQuery(conn, query, param=list(1, 'seatle', '98876'))

dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not run):

```
# Install and initialise packages:

necessary_packages <- c("DBI", "odbc")

new_packages <- necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]

if(seq_along(new_packages) > 0){install.packages(new_packages, dependencies = TRUE)}

lapply(necessary_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

# Create vectors thats values are to be used in query: 

AddressID_vec <- 1 

City_vec <- 'seatle' 

PostalCode_vec <- '98876'

# Connect to DB: 

conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),

                       Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",

                       Server = serverName,

                       Database = dbName,

                       UID = username,

                       PWD = pasword,

                       port = 1433)

# Concatenate base query and vecs:

query <- paste0("insert into dbo.address (AddressID, City, PostalCode) values (", 

               AddressID_vec,

               ", ",

               City_vec,

               ", ",

               PostalCode_vec,

               ")"
# Send Query: 

dbSendQuery(conn, query)


# Close Connection: 

dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I know how to construct a query string this way. Do you know how to use ‘param’ in dbSendQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

From the `DBI::dbSendQuery` docs

> This method is for SELECT queries only

While your question is on managing Microsoft SQL Server connections with DBI, I think the problem lies with the choice of DBI functions you are using for your parameterised INSERT statement. If so, the below example may be useful despite being based on an SQLite database.

```r
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
# Create in-memory SQLite db
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

# Create the `address` table to insert into
res <- DBI::dbSendQuery(conn,
            "CREATE TABLE address (
            `AddressID` INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY,
            `City` TEXT,
            `PostalCode` TEXT
            )")

DBI::dbClearResult(res)


statement = "INSERT INTO address (AddressID, City, PostalCode) VALUES (?,?,?)"

# We can pass parameters directly to dbSendStatement
res <- DBI::dbSendStatement(
    conn, 
    statement, 
    params = list(1, 'Seattle', '98876')
)

DBI::dbClearResult(res)

DBI::dbReadTable(conn, "address")
#>   AddressID    City PostalCode
#> 1         1 Seattle      98876

# We can pass multiple sets of values using dbBind()
res <- DBI::dbSendStatement(conn, statement)
DBI::dbBind(res, list(2, "fooville", "12345"))
DBI::dbBind(res, list(3, "barborough", "54321"))
DBI::dbClearResult(res)

DBI::dbReadTable(conn, "address")
#>   AddressID       City PostalCode
#> 1         1    Seattle      98876
#> 2         2   fooville      12345
#> 3         3 barborough      54321

DBI::dbDisconnect(conn)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>